# how to change each consecutive div order?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to move the div above another div , It has been asked before on forum , but this is somewhat different thing.

```css
#A {background-color: pink;}
#B {background-color: yellow;}
#C {background-color: lightblue;}
#D {background-color: lightgray;}
```

```html
<div id="A">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="B">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="C">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="D">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
```

I found this code

```
$('#third').insertBefore('#second');
```

to move up third class. But this  only works when there is single div . 
How can we move up third class in each ID.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what result you expect. Can you include a snippet with it? You should also tag your question as html while you're at it.

Comment: Snippet is there , I want to move class third above class second.
for some reasons i cant edit html

Comment: So what you want is for you to have a hierarchy like `A>1/3/2, B>1/3/2, C> 1/3/2, D> 1/3/2`?

Comment: Yes  thats what i want

Comment: @Help did you tried the flexbox solution? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33881734/5035890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each element with third as a class. Insert the object before the sibling with the second class.

```
$('.third').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.insertBefore($this.siblings('.second'))
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ctxpkLws/

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish this with flexbox and no JavaScript at all:

```css
#A {
    background-color: pink;
}
#B {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#C {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#D {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#A, #B, #C, #D {
    display:flex;    
    flex-direction:column;
}
.first {
    order:0;
}
.second {
    order:2;
}
.third {
    order:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
    <div class="first">This is first test</div>
    <div class="second">This is second test</div>
    <div class="third">This is third test</div>
</div>
<div id="B">
    <div class="first">This is first test</div>
    <div class="second">This is second test</div>
    <div class="third">This is third test</div>
</div>
<div id="C">
    <div class="first">This is first test</div>
    <div class="second">This is second test</div>
    <div class="third">This is third test</div>
</div>
<div id="D">
    <div class="first">This is first test</div>
    <div class="second">This is second test</div>
    <div class="third">This is third test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really the best and cleanest and performance solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.map()` , setting `context` of jQuery object passed to `.insertBefore()` to `this.parentElement`

```js
$(".third").map(function() {
  $(this).insertBefore($(".second", this.parentElement))
})
```

```css
#A {background-color: pink;}
#B {background-color: yellow;}
#C {background-color: lightblue;}
#D {background-color: lightgray;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="B">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="C">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="D">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this. First I'd add common class to parent divs and then loop trough and move elements. Just like this:

```
<div id="A" class="someClass">
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="B" class="someClass">>
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="C" class="someClass">>
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
<div id="D" class="someClass">>
    <div class="first">This is first test </div>
    <div class="second">This is second test </div>
    <div class="third">This is third test </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($('.someClass'), function() {
        $('#third', this).insertBefore('#second');
    });
});
```